# Extended WPF Toolkit Rich Text Box in ListBox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, richtextbox, observablecollection

I am trying to bind a RichTextBox in a list view to no avail.  If I do not wrap the RichTextBox in the listview and only assign it to the class, it works just fine.  But as soon as I try to assign to the list view it will not display the text, but does show the proper number of items.

Example:

```
    <ListBox Name="lstBook" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="auto">           
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <extToolkit:RichTextBox Margin="5" 
                                BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="1"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Notes, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                Height="100" 
                                Width="425">
                        <extToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                            <extToolkit:RtfFormatter />
                        </extToolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                    </extToolkit:RichTextBox>                       
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

C# Code

```
public class Data: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private string _notes = "";

    public string Notes
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set { _notes = value; OnPropertyChanged("Notes"); }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Notes;
    }
}
```

Code to populate:

```
        ObservableCollection<Data> datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        Data d = new Data
                     {
                         Notes =
                             @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch This is the }{\b\ltrch RichTextBox}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}}}"
                     };

        datas.Add(d);

        d = new Data();
        d.Notes = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch This is the }{\b\ltrch RichTextBox}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}}}";

        datas.Add(d);

        lstBook.ItemsSource = datas;
```

What am I missing?  The listbox show two records, but no text is displayed in the Rtf box.

Thanks...

Comment: `datas` is not a correct word. `data` is plural already. But probably that is not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding mode is `OneWayToSource`. The source in this case is the `Data` instance, so you are pushing data from the `RichTextBox` back to your `Notes` property, *but not the other direction*.

Change your binding mode to `OneWay` or `TwoWay`, depending on what you're trying to achieve.